# How to update a document when a document is added to a specified collection in cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 collections in my firestore (global and local) and when I add a doc to local I need to update a field in the global doc by 1

Below is the code I have for the same. I am very new to this so I might have some syntactical error as well, please do highlight if you find any.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello world");
}); // For testing, even this is not being deployed

exports.updateGlobal = functions.firestore
  .document("/local/{id}")
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log(snapshot.data());
    return admin
      .firebase()
      .doc("global/{id}")
      .update({
        total: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
     });
  });
```

The Terminal says "function failed on loading user code"
Before this, it showed something along the lines of "admin is undefined" or "cannot access *firestore* of undefined" which I'm unable to replicate now.

This is a part of a react app which has normal firestore working through **firebase npm module**
Any other info needed regarding the issue I'll edit the question accordingly, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to loading the `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin` modules, you need to initialize an `admin` app instance from which Cloud Firestore changes can be made, as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

//...
```

---

I see another problem in your CF. You need to use the `context` object to get the value of `id`.

```
exports.updateGlobal = functions.firestore
  .document("/local/{id}")
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    
   const docId = context.params.id;

    return admin
      .firebase()
      .doc("global/" + docId)
      .update({
        total: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
     });
  });
```

You can also use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as follows:

```
    return admin
      .firebase()
      .doc(`global/${docId}`)
      //...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, although I did try this before, it didn't work that time idk why. Anyway, does ```doc( "/collection/{id}" )```  work same as ```collection("collection").doc("{id}")``` ?

Comment: See the update, I realized that you need to use the `context` object to get the value of `id`.